# Is it ok to kill guards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I do know I can kill them using a bow and nobody will care, if I don't get noticed.

Does it have any side effects? I do know that they "help" me when a dragon attacks, but they are useless and I have to kill the dragon myself. Is it ok to kill all the guards? will they re-spawn?

Comment: just make sure you shoot them in the knee.

Comment: Heehee. Must try to stop making that joke now, it'll be ruined soon! :)

Comment: Eventually the Joke will be sitting in a pub and saying "I used to be funny, until I got an arrow in the knee."

Comment: Just make sure you also kill any witnesses.

Comment: @John Isaacks are you sure thats true? if I kill all witnesses there will be no bounty?

Comment: @IAdapter Whenever I kill all witnesses, after killing the last witness it tells me "Last witness killed 1000 bounty removed" or something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guards do respawn, so if they don't notice you killing a guard it doesn't make that much of a difference.

Answer (score 5):

You can pretty much kill everyone you like in Skyrim, however there are consequences if you are caught.  If you kill a guard without anyone seeing you, you will have no witness to the crime, and should be in the clear.

Comment: coming from Oblivion or Morrowind its very weird that you can do it.

Comment: One should note the exception of "essential" NPCs:  http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Essential_NPCs